# ARM InvalidTemplateDeployment: Required property '$schema' not found in JSON

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I receive the following errors when attempting to deploy an exported Azure Resource Template:

```
"The template is invalid. Error: 'Required property '$schema' not found in
JSON.

"Domain name is already taken"
```

**Error Content:**

The error content is as follows:

> {"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","details":[{"code":"DeploymentPreflightValidationFailed","target":"/subscriptions/<SOME_GUID_VALUE>/resourceGroups/<SOME_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>-Resource/providers/Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/<SOME_ARM_TEMPLATE_NAME>/versions/0.0","message":"The
> template is invalid. Error: 'Required property '$schema' not found in
> JSON. Path '', line 1, position
> 2.'"},{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Domain name is already taken"}],"message":"The template deployment
> 'Microsoft.Template-20220817090827' is not valid according to the
> validation procedure. The tracking id is
> 'c27e8ad4-6d96-46e9-92ed-ac8d5f462bf6'. See inner errors for
> details."}

**Observations:**

I have observed the following:

- The [latest schema path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#template-format) appears to match what I have listed.

**Template:**

```
{

"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "vulnerabilityAssessments_Default_storageContainerPath": {
        "type": "SecureString"
    },
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error regarding the `$schema` property is not referring to the `$schema` of the template itself, but is instead coming back from preflight (validation) of one of the `Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/versions` resources in your template.

I can repro this myself with the following file I exported (note that `Export` is stripping out the contents of `mainTemplate`, which I believe is the root cause of the issue, as it doesn't contain the expected `$schema` property).

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "templateSpecs_asdgasdg_name": {
            "defaultValue": "asdgasdg",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs",
            "apiVersion": "2022-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('templateSpecs_asdgasdg_name')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/versions",
            "apiVersion": "2022-02-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('templateSpecs_asdgasdg_name'), '/v1')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs', parameters('templateSpecs_asdgasdg_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mainTemplate": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My team at Microsoft owns the Export Template API - I will follow up internally on this.

Comment: Is there a support Id that I can use to track the status of this issue?